# Does OP see [mcve] link when question is closed as "needs debugging details"?

Tags: discussion

I was about to type "See [mcve]", but then decided to vote-close it instead.

---

### [image]

What makes me confused:

- there is no link to [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), maybe it's not visible to me, but to OP?
- "Debugging details" links to [help/closed-questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It's good to read about *general* close reasons, but it's completely useless to guide what details (called debugging) OP has to supply.

Does OP sees what I see? Should I manually add [mcve] in comments? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61636636/1997232) is the question.

Comment: Related feature request (in other words, no, there is no link): [Put a direct link to the MCVE help page on the closure notice for “needs debugging details”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397048/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey, thanks, there is another problem (not going to report it): meta search is [awful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=mcve%20need%20debugging%20details). Perhaps you can give me a hint how you found duplicate so I'll be able to find it next time?

Comment: Oh, I just remembered seeing this the other day... I think I did a search for "link mcve"? SO search has been awful since the beginning, but I actually used it for this. Otherwise I use Bing or Google with `site:meta.stackoverflow.com`, which tends to get results from Meta SE also (from before the switch).

Comment: I post a canned comment with magic link [mre] & summarizing it. User Strawberry gives a link to their self-answered meta question. Re search: Use google. Find out how to use advanced features. Like site:.