# Wrong links in "need debugging details" close message

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, close-reasons, hyperlinks

The close message for "needs debugging details" contains two links. These links can be helpful, but the placements of these links do not make sense, and looks like an editing mistake.

The close message text is:

> **Closed**. This question needs [debugging details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently
> accepting answers.
>
> Edit the question to include [desired behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), a specific problem or
> error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This
> will help others answer the question.

The first link "[debugging details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)" leads to https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

That page describes some close reason, but it says nothing about debugging details. The link should probably be on the word *"closed"* or *"not currently accepting answers"*. I am not sure we have a help page specifically for *"debugging details"*, but perhaps we should.

The second link "[desired behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" leads to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

This page contains some general information about what is on-topic, but the only mention of *"desired behaviour"* is an exact copy of the phrase in the close reason.
There is no further explanation what *"desired behaviour"* is, so linking these two words makes no sense.

(After that, the
words *"shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem"* are really begging for a link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
which contains probably the most relevant information about this close reason.
but we already have a feature requests and a discussion for that specific issue: [Put a direct link to the MCVE/MRE help page on the closure notice for "needs debugging details"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397048)
[Does OP see [mcve] link when question is closed as "needs debugging details"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397221/does-op-see-mcve-link-when-question-is-closed-as-needs-debugging-details.))

Comment: that admittedly does look pretty similar, but in my defence, that question is a *feature request* from two years ago to include the mcve link, while my main focus is a *bug report* about two clearly wrong link anchors. would it help if I reduce the focus of this bug report to only that issue?

Comment: There's also [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397221/does-op-see-mcve-link-when-question-is-closed-as-needs-debugging-details)

Comment: And [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401282/link-text-does-not-reflect-page-that-is-the-destination-of-the-link/401309#401309)

Comment: I removed all mentions of mcve form my question, except in the last paragraph, where I list these previous questions about mcve. Is there anything else I could do to make this question more distinct? I really do not think we have already resolved the wrong link issue.

Comment: It definitely hasn't been resolved, that's why the question that Robert linked isn't marked as [[meta-tag:status-completed]]. Are you just trying to make this distinct to keep it from getting closed because you think/hope a new question will bring more attention to getting the problem solved? Or do you *actually* think it is a distinct issue? (If the latter, please explain how it is different. I'm still not getting it.)

Comment: I think the inclusion of the mcve link would be a significant improvement, as was discussed,but that seems a distinct issue from the wrong words used for the existing links, so I want to focus this bug report on only that issue. There are also certainly further improvements possible, as evidently discussed before. I am hoping that by focusing this question on a single bug, perhaps that specific problem will get addressed, althought I do admit that I don't understand what stopped the previous more general feature request from being addressed. Perhaps I lack some further insight into this issue.