# Closing as lacking debugging details gives an unhelpful message to the poster

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, minimal-reproducible-example

I just noticed that if a question is closed as lacking debugging details/minimum verifiable example, then the poster just get this unhelpful message in their face:

> Closed. This question needs [debugging details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.

Where the link leads to a page which does not explain what's required to fix the post. Only by reading the fine print on the linked page, we are taken to a relevant page here:

> Off-topic because… - each community decides which specific topics are and are not allowed on their site. You can see this list of off-topic subjects for this site by [viewing this help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

And there we finally find the actual, helpful advise:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

---

It isn't sensible to expect any user to find their way through all of this to the actual relevant information regarding why their question was closed and how they should improve it. I believe the site used to give the text quoted last above as advice. Then someone changed it just for the sake of changing things...

**Feature request:**

When a question is closed for lacking debugging details/MCVE, the following text should be displayed to the OP and anyone else viewing the closed question:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Umm, this is what I currently see for [the "needs debugging details" post notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Jj4.png), including the "*Edit the question to include [desired behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question.*" part. Whether it's ideal or not, it's more than an "unhelpful message".

Comment: related (but not exact dupe): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408184/145999

Comment: I agree that the link is a duplicate (the MCVE link is the key info) but nobody has done jack about that feature request since that was posted in April 2020. The root of the problem is the poorly considered close reason changes that happened some 2-3 years back. Those changes should have been rolled back, but some pointy-haired boss apparently invested a lot of prestige in them. But the site has changed owners since then, so maybe this could be fixed now?

Comment: @AndrewT. Still the poster must find their way through multiple links to get to the MCVE/MRE link. It's neither easy to understand nor to find.

Comment: Also ironically, as some are casting dupe votes on this meta post, I get "Some community members have suggested a similar question that may solve your problem. " How can it do that if the question has no answers other than a subjective rant by a random user and no acknowledgement what-so-ever by staff. It's pretty dubious design that the site lets us pick a dupe target which has not been resolved either.

Comment: @Lundin: I disagree on the dupe target comment; the idea of closing as duplicate (of a question) is to funnel discussion and answers in a single place which is a _good_ intention. The fact that nobody replied to the question is independent, if unhelpful.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The thing is that as soon as something gets closed as duplicate, the discussion dies. Unless we all go to the dupe target and go stir things up anew. Also, this is the usual flaw with meta moderation: "you can't discuss this, we already discussed this 1.5 years ago". In this case absolutely nothing has happened in that time, so I can agree with closing the post. But in the general scenario, discussion-tag posts shouldn't be closed as duplicates, especially not to some very old post.

Comment: @Lundin: I think there's 2 situations: (1) the old post is irrelevant, then the question should clarify why -- for example, it's questioning the very resolution of the post or (2) the old post dead-ended, then... maybe we should reverse the duplicate tagging? That is, reopen this post and close the _old_ post as duplicate. Then we get the best of both worlds: single question for single subject to funnel the discussion, and recent question to ensure activity/visibility? I'll vote for re-open as I think we are in situation (2).

Comment: @MatthieuM. If you're going with route 2, then you should try and get a gold-hammer on board, otherwise it takes up to 10 votes to complete the reversal. That being said, I'm not sure this approach sets a good precedent. Do we really want users posting essentially identical questions just because the discussion on the previous one has died down without reaching any particular conclusion? I'd personally prefer some way of "bumping" the old post if possible.

Comment: I have a gold hammer so I could have re-opened this at any time. But after I became aware of the duplicate, it's obvious to me that the company doesn't care and/or got someone in middle-management who's invested prestige in the poorly considered close reason changes. I'll try better to focus my energy on the non-profit communities instead of wasting time trying to improve this site... it's been a lost cause for many years now.

Comment: Why the heck are we re-opening this? It's clearly a duplicate; you're asking exactly the same thing. Asking the same thing over and over again doesn't make it happen faster; it just makes people irritated.

Comment: @CodyGray Why are you putting status completed on feature requests that blatantly obviously have not been completed? It has not even gotten status:planned.

Comment: No, it's been done. Check again.