# Link text does not reflect page that is the destination of the link

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, help-center, post-notice

The following notice shows at the top of a question that has been closed due to lack of Debugging details.

> This question needs debugging details.

should be changed to

> This question is closed.

to reflect the page that the link points to; the debugging details link points to the following [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) page. The close question page does not contain any information about Debugging details question closure, so the title of this link is misleading.

[image: Closed. This question needs debugging details. It is not currently accepting answers.]

Yes, I realize that the page itself states:

> Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question.

But the debugging details link is there for a reason. It's that link that I am questioning.

A possible solution would also be to just change:

> This question needs [debugging details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.

to

> This question is [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).  It is not currently accepting answers.

Or the [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) page should define what is meant by having a "question closed due to lack of debugging details" section, or "debugging details closed" should have its own page.

Comment: Huh. I would've expected that to link to the MRE help topic. The need for something to link to from a "debugging" close reason was the reason why that page was originally created...

Comment: That was my thought as well.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/63930440/1841839

Comment: This worked just fine before SO changed the wording of all close reasons just for the heck of it, a year back or so.

Comment: @Lundin i think the wording was probably changed to be kinder and less accusational, but your probably right.

Comment: @DaImTo It's not very kind to close someone's question without telling them why, or how to improve it...

Comment: @DaImTo I have my suspicions about the programming experience of the people who decided the wording needed changing and wrote the replacement.

Comment: I am also not sure if this is supposed to mean "details of the debugging that has been done so far" or "details that can be used for debugging".

Comment: [Details or clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), [focused](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) are also linked to the same closed question help page, the meaning of those reasons is explained though, whereas "debugging details" are not and should probably be included. However "Edit the question to include [desired behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" below directly links to an explanation that an MRE is needed.

Comment: If a user, ESL or no, does not understand 'debugging details', they cannot program computers and should seek to learn more basics of software development before posting their questions on SO:(  Why are so many teachers/TA/profs failing their students by not teaching basics before setting assignments, (or, in the case of uni, directing students to read up on software development, esp. testing/debugging), and pointing them at SO?

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not sure it's the responsibility of a university to teach how to debug code, no more than it's the responsibility of the university to teach their student how to proofread their reports. Lower level education is a different matter though. I was never "taught" to do it myself, but I also jumped right in at university.

Comment: @Scratte ' I'm not sure it's the responsibility of a university to teach how to debug code', neither am I, but the students should be at least aware of design/code/test/debug, so that they can look up those terms, before they are let loose on 'Hello World':)

Comment: @MartinJames Assignments are a critical component of teaching, including teaching how to debug. There is only so much that lectures and books can teach.

Comment: I posted something related to this a while back: [Put a direct link to the MCVE help page on the closure notice for “needs debugging details”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397048/put-a-direct-link-to-the-mcve-help-page-on-the-closure-notice-for-needs-debuggi). Linking to the "Why are some questions closed?" page *really* should not be the 1st thing the OP reads for this type of closure. It's also inconvenient to make them jump through several links to find the MCVE page.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, exactly!  The students should be doing the assignments, and that includes an attempt at testing/debugging.  That's when they really learn, rather than being taught -digging out for themselves why their linked-list segfaults/AV's.  Profs should demand a diary of what the students did after their code compiled and before it worked, (or they gave up:)   To me, a list of 'it did this, I tried that', would be much more impressive, and deserve a much higher mark, than working code that the student may, or may not, have authored:)

Comment: I think a number of you may have misunderstood my point.  Actually that question does not relate to my question which is a suggestion that **This question needs debugging** details. should be changed to **This question is closed.** to reflect the page that the link points to.   I am not requesting a link to MCVE i am requesting a clarification of a link.

Comment: @DaImTo Why is changing the text better than changing the link? I think that a generic page that's the same network wide just isn't helpful for a Community-specifc close reason so linking to it is not useful at all.

Comment: @MartinJames It is not always obvious exactly _what_ debugging details are relevant or expected.

Comment: @Catija I am happy with what ever solution you guys come up with.  I just have a thing for consistency.   Either way works.

Answer (score 21):

> Or the closed question page should define what is meant by having a "question closed due to lack of debugging details" section, or "debugging details closed" should have its own page.

This concern was first raised fairly soon after that close reason (or rather, the precursor to the precursor to the precursor to that close reason) was first introduced.

Back then, we opted for your last suggestion and [created a new page to house guidance for the close reason.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258845/can-we-create-a-help-center-topic-that-outlines-what-a-sscce-mwe-means-for-sta)

That page eventually became https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Given all that history... And the continuing popularity of the guidance... I'd recommend [Cat's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401282/link-text-does-not-reflect-page-that-is-the-destination-of-the-link/401308#401308):

> My preference here would be to edit the generic link to help/closed-questions and have it point to the MRE/MCVE page instead.

Answer (score 19):

There's two (three) solutions here:

1. Edit the text to match the current standard text for most of the other Community-specific reasons:

   > Closed. This question does not meet [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.
2. Keep the text but actually pick a better link, like the MCVE link recommended [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401282/link-text-does-not-reflect-page-that-is-the-destination-of-the-link#comment796837_401282), in [an MSO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397048/put-a-direct-link-to-the-mcve-help-page-on-the-closure-notice-for-needs-debuggi), or in a [request on the announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390887/new-post-notices-closed-on-hold-etc-rolling-out-on-stack-overflow/390892#390892) from when the post notices were rolled out.

Technically we can change both, too... if "debugging details" isn't clear enough, even with a link to a better page, we can go with different text.

The Help Center article linked in the post notice is generic - it's the same everywhere on the network - OK, it's not *currently* but it should be. Nothing on it is specific to SO and it doesn't even mention Community-specific close reasons and... well... it still refers to them as "off-topic"... which ... well, that's on me. I'll get the text fixed up.

Regardless, for now, that page is going to continue to stay generic but we are looking at creating a lot more help for close voters and users with closed questions in the near future.

My preference here would be to edit the generic link to `help/closed-questions` and have it point to the [MRE/MCVE page instead](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Neither of the currently linked pages are particularly helpful to users who have their questions closed for this specific reason, so it seems like it'd only further frustrate people already likely confused or frustrated by having their question closed in the first place.

I'm curious whether y'all think the link to `/help/on-topic` is helpful or not and if the placement of the link works there. I'm thinking it may just be distracting. I generally think that page is great to have but I'm concerned we're trying to force it in where it won't work.

If we go this route I'll mark this [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) and [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) the other question.

Comment: If a post is closed because it needs "debugging details" then it makes sense to link to /help/minimal-reproducible-example. If it's closed with the banner saying "Stack Overflow guidelines" then there's no knowing if it actually lacked debugging details, so linking to /help/closed-questions makes more sense there. This all depends on the quality of the closures of course. If there's a risk that users will pick "needs debugging details" when that doesn't fit, then linking to /help/closed-questions would be better. Also, we'd like all the users to read all the pages, no? :)

Comment: Personally I think the 2nd option is much better. It is ideal to have contextually-useful close reasons, each of which link to a help page on how to avoid such problems.